# Is there anyway to find out exact resource usage of nginx-rtmp?

Tags: nginx, streaming, rtmp

I'm currently working on a streaming project that uses the Nginx-RTMP protocol, but our project manager needs some resource estimations for 1K users, I'm new to RTMP world and tried to find some documentation about RTMP resource usage and stuff like this but I couldn't find any, hope u guys can lead me to some tips and tricks for RTMP resource usage.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.